# Create own footer menu in Wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I do have two menus in my Wordpress-Page which are called

```
Mainmenu(Primary Menu)
Footer
```

I associated the "Mainmenu" to the header of the website. I want the footer of the Wordpresspage to look exactly like the header, only difference should be the Links in it. It should not be taken from the "Mainmenu", but from the menu called "Footer". The function of the Header looks like this:

```
echo '<nav id="rtp-primary-menu" role="navigation" class="rtp-nav-wrapper' . apply_filters( 'rtp_mobile_nav_support', ' rtp-mobile-nav' ) . '">';
rtp_hook_begin_primary_menu();

/* Call wp_nav_menu() for Wordpress Navigaton with fallback wp_list_pages() if menu not set in admin panel */
if ( function_exists( 'wp_nav_menu' ) && has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) ) {
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'container' => '', 'menu_class' => 'menu rtp-nav-container clearfix', 'menu_id' => 'rtp-nav-menu', 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'depth' => apply_filters( 'rtp_nav_menu_depth', 4 ) ) );
} else {
    echo '<ul id="rtp-nav-menu" class="menu rtp-nav-container clearfix">';
    wp_list_pages( array( 'title_li' => '', 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'number' => '5', 'depth' => apply_filters( 'rtp_nav_menu_depth', 4 ) ) );
    echo '</ul>';
}

rtp_hook_end_primary_menu();
echo '</nav>';
```

The Theme i am using is rtPanel. Can anyone tell me how i simply can change this function in the way that it will load its content from the Menu called "Footer" and not from the Primary Menu which is "Mainmenu"?

Please dont worry about the CSS and everything, i will take care about this. I really just want to now how i have to change this function to load the "Footer"-Menu in it and not the Primary-Menu(Mainmenu).

As an Attachment how it look in the menu:

[image]

Thank you very much advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really simple, in fact when you start developing wordpress theme this might be one of the very first items you need to learn.

You need to register a menu location for footer seciton. You can learn more in [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menu)

```
 register_nav_menu( 'footer', __( 'Footer Menu', 'theme-slug' ) );
```

This will register the menu for you. Since you already have the menu location just find the location parameter. We're going to use that in the following code. For now assume it 'footer' like the above one. And the code for the footer menu according to your referenced code-

```
echo '<nav id="rtp-primary-menu" role="navigation" class="rtp-nav-wrapper' . apply_filters( 'rtp_mobile_nav_support', ' rtp-mobile-nav' ) . '">';
//rtp_hook_begin_primary_menu(); // we better disable this hook as it intends for the header primary menu

/* Call wp_nav_menu() for Wordpress Navigaton with fallback wp_list_pages() if menu not set in admin panel */
if ( function_exists( 'wp_nav_menu' ) ) {
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'container' => '', 'menu_class' => 'menu rtp-nav-container clearfix', 'menu_id' => 'rtp-nav-menu', 'theme_location' => 'footer', 'depth' => apply_filters( 'rtp_nav_menu_depth', 4 ) ) );
} else {
    echo '<ul id="rtp-nav-menu" class="menu rtp-nav-container clearfix">';
    wp_list_pages( array( 'title_li' => '', 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'number' => '5', 'depth' => apply_filters( 'rtp_nav_menu_depth', 4 ) ) );
    echo '</ul>';
}

//rtp_hook_end_primary_menu(); // we better disable this hook as it intends for the header primary menu
echo '</nav>';
```

Notice the `theme_location` parameter in `wp_nav_menu()` function? This is the one which plays behind to get you menu correctly.

Now play around with CSS and you might get what you intend.

Hope this might help you.

Comment: Hey maksbd19! Thank you very much for your quick answer, but it not seems to be working. If i change it like that the footer is just empty!??

Comment: what is the name of the location of your footer menu? You must pass this name as parameter, or else its not gonna work. And also make sure your location has a menu in the admin panel. Finally I made a mistake, please update your code as well.

Comment: Thank you! How can i find out the location? I uploaded a picture for you so you can see how it looks in the menu.

Comment: Footer menu location is not registered. use the first `register_nav_menu` code inside yours themes `function.php` file. Then you will see another checkbox below the "Primary Navigation" checkbox. Then set that menu like you did for primary menu.

Comment: You should wear a cape, fly through Germany and help people like me. In other words, its working perfectly now! Thank you very much for your time and your effort! ;)

Comment: The pleasure is all mine :)